# Export from GAMs to a text file

Tags: gams-math

After solving my model  in GAMS, I have 2 value,  val1 and val2.

How can I export the value of these variable(val1 ,val2)  to text file , e.g. to .text or CSV format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
    File results / results.txt /;
    put results;
    put "Objective", z.l /;

    putclose;
```